# express js server process curl request twice

Tags: node.js, express, curl, upload, multer

When I post a request to my website like this:

```
curl -F data=@data http://server:port/path
{"error":"req.file undefined"}
```

I get the answer for the case that req.file is undefined. See my Code:

```
 var multer = require("multer");
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    //stuff
 })
 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

 router.post('/path', upload.single("data"), function(req, res, next){ 
   console.log(req.file);

   if(!req.file){
     res.json({"error": "req.file undefined"});
     return;   
   }   
   //dostuff   
   res.json({"error": "hurray"}); 
 });
```

On my server Side everything works fine, the output is:

```
undefined
POST /path 200 1.535 ms - 15
POST /path 200 1.535 ms - 15
POST /path - - ms - -
POST /path - - ms - -
{ fieldname: 'data',
  originalname: 'data.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  destination: 'path/my-uploads',
  filename: 'data-201899-1028283.txt',
  path: 'path/my-uploads/data-201899-1028283.txt',
  size: 38 
}
```

So I see that before the file is uploaded the `console.log(req.file)` logs `undefined` and that this is what I get as answer on my client curl side, but how do I keep this from happening?
I use `multer 1.4.0` where `onParseEnd` and `onFileUploadComplete` are **depricated**.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you try by raising an issue in github repo of multer? I think you will get some help from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did raise my question there: 
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/666
It turns out something is up with my cURL request. Multer works just fine.
Though atm I don't know what the problem with curl is.